# How to reset a JDBC Connection object?

Tags: java, jdbc

How to reset a JDBC Connection object (that is, a java.sql.Connection object)?

I have explored the concept of connection pooling. When a connection pool is used, a Connection object can be recycled. But how can a connection pool recycle a Connection object? I think that a connection needs to be "reset" (for example, if it is in a transaction, then perhaps rollback it, but there may be more things to reset) before it can be reused. But I cannot find such a "reset" method in the Java documentation about the class java.sql.Connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about what you as a user of a connection should do, then that is simple: call `close()` on the connection. Closing the logical connection will signal to the connection pool that the connection is available for reuse, and the connection pooling manager is then responsible for performing the necessary reset, invalidation of statement handles, etc.

If you are talking about what you as the implementer of a connection pooling manager should do, that is where things become complicated.

Historically, JDBC provides no way to 'reset' a `java.sql.Connection`, other than by your own code (or your third-party connection pool) remembering the initial configuration, and restoring it after use, and keeping track of objects like statements and result sets and closing them when the connection is returned to the pool.

Originally, the intended way to reset connections in JDBC was for an application server to use a driver's `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` as a factory for `javax.sql.PooledConnection` objects. These `PooledConnection` objects serve as handles for physical connections to be held in a connection pool (to be clear, `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is not a connection pool, it is a data source **for** a connection pool). The application server would then expose a `javax.sql.DataSource` handing out logical `Connection` objects, where on `Connection.close()`, the driver specific implementation of `PooledConnection` would take care of any necessary reset of a connection (though JDBC underspecifies what is 'necessary').

However, in practice this route is hardly ever used because support in drivers was (and often still is) spotty, inconsistent or downright incorrect, and JDBC wasn't clear enough on exactly what needed to be done when the logical connection was closed. The world has also shifted to using third-party connection pool libraries that do not use `ConnectionPoolDataSource`.

JDBC 4.3 (Java 9 and higher) introduced the methods [`Connection.beginRequest()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#beginRequest()) and [`Connection.endRequest()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#endRequest()) to be called by connection pooling managers, which would seem to fit such pattern, but unfortunately JDBC 4.3 doesn't actually specify what kind of things an implementation should or should not do in response to `beginRequest` and `endRequest`.

In short, there is no real general way to reset a connection in JDBC.

Comment: I am curious: Why is JDBC so complex on trying to support connection pooling? Isn't it sufficient if JDBC just adds an (optional) "reset" method to the java.sql.Connection interface and then leaves it for JDBC drivers to implement? Maybe a little more is needed, but this is the main idea. The ConnectionPoolDataSource approach is quite complex, which may be why few driver implements it properly.

Comment: @zhoudu I can't answer that, I wasn't a member of the JDBC EG at the time. However, it fits with component-based design that was popular when JDBC 2.0 (introducing the `javax.sql` package) was created, and it also provides a separation of concerns. If I had to guess, not putting a `reset` on `Connection` was to not overburden the API with things that should not be called by users of connections. And unfortunately, some things are really a case of either lack of consensus in the EG or - at least in JDBC 4.x - Oracle forcing their ideas on JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to close() method and reinitialize Connection object again.

close()
Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released